# File upload with intermittent connection in node.js

Tags: node.js

I want to upload a file with intermittent connection using node.js can anyone please help me how to do it.

Comment: Node.js as client or as server?

Answer (score 0):

[Flow.js](https://github.com/flowjs/flow.js) is a file upload library that can handle restarts for intermittent connection. Give it a try!